# How to play same animation 'reverse' with no selector and 'normal' on :active?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to use the same animation with no selector and with selector :active. The only difference is that I change the animation-direction. The result is that the browser plays the animation once (on page load). When I click the animation is not being played.

I could create two keyframes, with the same content and different names, then it works. But I don't like copy-paste code. So I'm tying to find a way to make this work. Any suggestions?

```
<style>
button.click {
  animation: click 0.5s 0s 1 reverse ease none;
}

button.click:active {
  animation: click 0.5s 0s 1 normal ease forwards;
}

@keyframes click {
0% {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

100% {
  margin-left: 2.5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 2.5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
}

</style>

<button class="click">test</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot restart the keyframe animation once its executed on page load, the only way is to give 2 keyframes as u said before.